# replace white space with ' \ ' in ruby to make them bash-readable

Tags: ruby, bash, path

How can I format `"hello bro"` to obtain `"hello\ bro"` in ruby.

When I use `"...".gsub /\s/,'\\ '`, I obtain "hello\\ bro" which bash cannot read. The '\ ' replacement has no effect.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you're trying to solve the right problem? If you're building a command line then maybe the multi-argument version of `system` or `Open3` would be better so that you can bypass the shell and all its quoting rules completely. There's also `Shellwords` if you must build command strings. Also keep in mind that the shell has more specially interpreted characters than just spaces.

Comment: `"hello bro"` and `"hello\ bro"` are the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `gsub` arguments are actually correct.  If you're running it through `irb`, it may not be obvious though - backslashes are escaped in the console output.  For instance:

```
irb(main):036:0> my_str = "hello bro".gsub /\s/, '\\ '
=> "hello\\ bro"
```

However, we'll see the expected string when we output the value of `my_str`:

```
irb(main):043:0> puts my_str
hello\ bro
```

That said, unless you're *absolutely* sure that spaces are the only characters you need to escape, you're better off using something like [Shellwords](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/shellwords/rdoc/Shellwords.html), as mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Thought I was going mad. Thanks for the `puts` trick!